# Browse and edit excel files via access vba

Tags: database

I am new to access vba….requesting to please guide for the below mentioned:
I want to create an access vba tool and its purpose is to browse multiple excel files only and update/edit all selected excel files by adding a new row on (as in the first row of sheet1) with a text as “ABC”. And, then it should save and close all the excel files.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, below is code for further reference.

```
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MySheetPath As String
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim varFile As Variant
With fDialog
   .AllowMultiSelect = True
   .Title = "Select File Location to Export XLSx :"
   .InitialFileName = ""
If .Show = True Then
   For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
     GetFileName = varFile
MySheetPath = GetFileName
Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)
Xl.Visible = True
XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(1)
Dim varInquiryID As Long
Dim varCentreFooter As String
Dim sHeader As String
varCentreFooter = " ABC "
XlSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = varCentreFooter

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Next
End If
End With

Set Xl = Nothing
Set XlBook = Nothing
Set XlSheet = Nothing
```